# How to create additional OAuth2 Access Tokens without user interaction

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a web service that makes use of the Authorization Code grant type to get an Access Token for user data on a Resource Server, together with a Refresh Token. Now my web service launches jobs at certain points in time that should also access this user data. However,

- there may be more than one job running at a time,
- the user is not necessarily around when the jobs are spawned, and
- the jobs may be long-running, in particular they may live longer than the validity of the Access Token.

My question is: How can I provide each job with an Access Token so that

- no user interaction is required for every single job launch, and
- each job can refresh its own Access Token if necessary, without invalidating other jobs' tokens?

While https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5 states that a refresh token can be used to obtain "*additional* access tokens" (emphasis mine), the spec is not so clear on whether the previous Access Token remains valid until it's expiry date (well, if it does not I wouldn't call it "additional"). Also, according to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-6 if a server issues a new Refresh Token to prevent replay attacks, then the old Refresh Token cannot be used any more, so now maybe I have an additional Access Token, but I can't really pass the Access Token and the new Refresh Token to the job, because if the job made use of that Refresh Token would then my web service couldn't use it any more.

Are there maybe any lesser-known flows that allow for this kind of unattended Access Token creation?

Answer (score 0):

Normally access tokens and refresh tokens are valid till the exipration time.
Having multiple access and refresh tokens are also allowed.
However a refresh token can be revoked under following scenarios

- the authorization server has revoked the refresh token
- the user has revoked their consent for authorization
- the refresh token has expired
- the authentication policy for the resource has changed

Since you are having the background jobs running. I suggest not to use JWT Tokens for authentication. Instead you can have your custom security standards.
Like custom API Key, UserAgent for Jobs and you can pass the user information with the requset or as custom-header as well.